# GWT multi-tenancy support using Locale and ClientBundle

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, multi-tenant, clientbundle

I'm trying to bring a multi-tenancy feature to my existing GWT app. Requirements are as follows

1. Use company specific CSS and images
2. Few changes to the texts
3. Some changes to the actual app logic

Currently my app has one ClientBundle which includes all images and CSS and is accessed via a static constant:

```
public interface MyRes extends ClientBundle {
    public static final MyRes RES =  GWT.create(myRes.class);
    ...
}
Image image = new Image(MyRes.RES.myLogo());
```

My texts are all inside one big Java properties file which is parsed in to an [GWT Messages Interface](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Messages.html).

My idea is to setup a different locale for the texts and [determine the locale via an URL parameter](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale#LocaleSpecifying). I'm still not sure how to load different ClientBundles depending on the company. Do I need to create an abstract ClientBundle and inherit that one into CompanyA and CompanyB ClientBundles?

My main question is, is whether this is a good solution or if there are other, my elegant ways.

Comment: You can do it at compile time or at runtime. Your choice. At compile, you'll have to build one GWT module per client, or one (more) permutation per client. At runtime, you have to download the rules you want and then execute some logic to determine what to show and how. Both solutions are not trivial to implement, though.

Comment: You can get pretty close to solution one with the appearance pattern and an additional property (like locale and useragent). Start with http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CellBackedWIdgets#Appearance_Pattern, and in your rebind rule, make each rule depend on each variation of the property being set.